# SimpleHTTPServer and SocketServer

Tags: python, python-2.7, socketserver, simplehttpserver

I have created a 'handler' python script as follows:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "Serving at port:", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I also have a javascript function, which sends information to the server a URL request.  This all works fine, when I run my handler script, and then my javascript, I can see all of the data from the JS in the terminal:

```
localhost.localadmin - - [20/Feb/2013] "GET /?var=data/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

What I would like to do, is be able to access this data from my handler script, ideally somethig like this:

```
data = httpd.server_forever()  #How do I do somethign like this
```

How do I accomplish such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inherit `SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` like this:

```
class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
  def do_GET(self):
      # Your code here
      print "Client requested:", self.command, self.path

      SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

PORT = 8000

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), MyHandler)

print "Serving at port:", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

That will print in console:

```
Client requested GET /?var=data/
```

Check documentation on [SimpleHTTPRequestHandler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html#SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler) and [BaseHTTPRequestHandler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler) for more information.

Comment: ok thanks its working, but is printing twice.  I've looking deep into the code but can't find why?  (Its not that big of a deal, just curious)

Comment: Actually It may have something to do with my .Js

Comment: If you are getting this output per connection:  
  
    `Client requested: GET /  `
`    localhost.localdomain - - [21/Feb/2013 00:38:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -  `
`    Client requested: GET /  
    localhost.localdomain - - [21/Feb/2013 00:38:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -  `
  
then there is probably something with your js.  
Or you just dont want this `localhost.localdomain - - [21/Feb/2013 00:38:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -` to be printed?

Comment: is there a way to check if it is succesful from my handler script?  i.e. check if the response is 200 ?

Comment: Try overriding `send_response` instead of do_GET:  class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def send_response(self, code, message=None):
        SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.send_response(self, code, message)
        print "Client requested:", self.command, self.path
        print "Code:", code